# Different spellcheck dictionaries for different chats in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, spell-check, irc

I am trying to use Thunderbird as an IRC client. So far so good, but it seems to only remember one spellchecking dictionary, while I use different languages on different channels. Is there a way to enable separate spellchecks for separate chats? An add-on maybe?

---

Edit: I've asked this question on [the Mozilla Support forums](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1238572). No answers so far.

Comment: Are you using different languages? If yes, I suggest the [Automatic Dictionary add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/automatic-dictionary-switching/) which remembers your language for each contact. I don't know how well it works for IRC.

Comment: @harrymc Just installed it and tried it in chat. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of another such add-on.